# Jquery Input file type manipulation in IE issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

Well i have a problem manipulating values of input type field in IE, it seems to work fine in firefox...

Here goes my issue:

I have created a fake upload button which when pressed actually clicks the real upload button(which is transparent, css fix and all), and after the file is chosen I actually obtain the filename and display it in a span area(all this fuss because my client wants custom look for the file uploader).

Well the real problem is with IE, whenever I upload a file, the filename isn't shown, i checked through the debugger IE just empties the input type file field.

Here goes the code:

```
<div class="right-pad">
   <p>Select an image file on your computer (4mb max).</p>
   <div class="btn-rect lightbox-btn btn-choose-file light-blue-btn" id="fakeUploadBtn">Choose File</div>                                    
   <div class="btn-rect lightbox-btn btn-choose-file light-blue-btn long-words-fix" id="upload-pic-file-name" ><p>No file chosen...</div>
   <input style="width:100%;position:relative;z-index: 10" id="realUploadBtn" name="image_upload_path" class="btn-rect lightbox-btn btn-choose-file light-blue-btn  real-upload" value="" type="file">                                                                                                        
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
                    $("#realUploadBtn").change(function() {
                        var fileName = $(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
                        $("#upload-pic-file-name").html(fileName);
                    });
                });

            $('#fakeUploadBtn').click(function() {

                $('#realUploadBtn').trigger('click');
            });
```

Solved the first part of my problem, well the second part seems like an all out IE issue, do refer to these links,
-> http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?181272-Need-help-with-Access-is-denied-error-in-IE
-> [Accessing File Data of file input in IE8 on the client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035318/accessing-file-data-of-file-input-in-ie8-on-the-client)

Comment: You should share your code.

Comment: I am new to this, it seems when i post my code it gets processed

Comment: Use `` around the code

Comment: looks really messy!! sorry

Comment: @ArvindBhardwaj: for large pieces of code, use code blocks, not inline code spans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first your code should be

```
$(function() {
                    $("#realUploadBtn").change(function() {
                        var fileName = $(this).val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
                        $("#upload-pic-file-name").html(fileName);
                    });


            $('#fakeUploadBtn').click(function() {

                $('#realUploadBtn').trigger('click');
     });
  });
```

and it is the browser default behavior IE don't Support this property

so you can use

```
$("input[name='attachment[]']").each(function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
    console.log(fileName);
});
```

You can't get the full path of the file, because it depends on the browser you use. The only common cross-browser value for an input file is the name of the file.

Comment: it ain't working, It seems like for some reason, IE doesn't like dev tinkering with the upload type fields. Of course i don't want the full path, just need to show the filename in a fake span area, for the look and feel of a upload menu.

Comment: Try It  $("#realUploadBtn").change(function() {
$("input[name='attachment[]']").each(function() {
    var fileName = $(this).val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
    console.log(fileName);
});
});

Comment: Umm, the filename shows up, but it seems, when the JS script obtains the filename from the input type field, it resets the fields as well.

Comment: now i think it time for you to use your logic i have give you a idea how you will get the name hope it works for you @user2977902

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll try what i can. But the thing is i have done what i actually needed in Firefox, the problems persists only in IE, so thought it was an IE issue(not the one in which i cant get the filename, the issue is the field getting cleared). Anywayz thanks for the helpful response.